# When is this graph Laplacian inequality true?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

Let $G$ be a simple, connected graph on $n$ vertices, and let $0 = \mu_1 < \mu_2 \le \cdots \le \mu_n$ and $\lambda_1 > \lambda_2 \ge \cdots \ge \lambda_n$ be the eigenvalues of $G$'s Laplacian and adjacency matrices, respectively. I am interested in determining when the inequality $$\delta \le \frac{\mu_2 + \mu_n}{2}$$ is true (where $\delta$ is the minimum degree of $G$). I don't believe it is always true, since if we consider a $d$-regular graph, we find that $$\delta > \frac{\mu_2 + \mu_n}{2} \Longleftrightarrow 2d > (d-\lambda_2) + (d-\lambda_n) \Longleftrightarrow \lambda_2 > |\lambda_n|,$$ which I believe I've seen before for some graphs.

From some searching, I've been able to find that $$\mu_2 \le \frac{n}{n-1}\delta \le \frac{n}{n-1}\Delta \le \mu_n,$$ ($\Delta$ is maximum degree of $G$) but I haven't been able to figure anything out just from that. Thank you for your help!

Comment: What make you think that there exists a characterization of graphs satisfying this inequality ?

Comment: For the counter-example, any $d$-regular non-bipartite graphs with 2 connected components will verify $d=\lambda_1=\lambda_2 > \vert \lambda_n\vert$

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'm admittedly not sure at all that there exists such a characterization, but it would be useful in a project I am working on if there is, so I figured I'd ask. In terms of your counterexample, I am only interested in cases where G is connected.

Comment: I ran some test, it might give you some insight. For order (# of vertices) up to $7$, all graphs verify the inequality. $3$ graphs on $8$ vertices (out of $11117$ non-isomorphic connected graphs) do not verify the strict inequality, but do verify the equality. For graphs on $9$ vertices (out of $261080$ non-isomorphic connected graph), $5$ of them don't verify the inequality, and for $2$ of them it's an equality, for $3$ of them it is strictly reverse. here are the 3 graphs (in graph6 format) : HCQRRQs , HCQRThi , HQhVTh[ .

Comment: My guess would be to find some find graphs verifying (and not-verifying) the inequality, with a higher order (looking at random graphs), try to see what they have/don't have in common to work up a conjecture. And then probably use Courant-Fischer inequalities and spectral bounds on edge cuts to prove it. Let us know if you find something!

Comment: Wow, thank you so much - I'll take a look and get back if I figure anything out!

Comment: For info, I've had a (very) quick second though, and it's quite easy to construct graphs that will not verify the inequality : take for instance two disjoint complete graph on $n$ vertices, and join them by one (or few) edges. $\mu_2$ is gonna be very small (because it represents the algebraic connectivity of the graph, here very small), while $\mu_n$ will be of the order of $\Delta=\delta+1$. So the inequality will fail. Lots of similar construction are possible. I don't think you'll be able to find any simple conjecture.